# post-ban for three questions with no rating

Tags: support, post-ban

I am banned from asking questions due to having no rating on three questions, this doesn't really seem necessary.  My questions were valid, except no one up voted them, so this leads me to question ban?  If anyone can help me not do this in the future and help me out right now, please do!  Thanks!

Comment: You have a deleted question that was downvoted and closed, in addition to the three existing ones you have.

Comment: I have a deleted question?  Hmmm, don't seem to remember it.

Comment: How can you tell this, and can you see what the question was about?

Comment: I'm a moderator - I can see deleted questions on users' profiles. You'll need the link to see it - here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058908/adding-a-favorites-page-with-members It seems to have been auto-deleted for spending too long being downvoted and closed with little recourse even after your edit.

Comment: Wow, that was a long time ago, when I was first learning code.  So to be able to ask questions again, what can I do?

Comment: You will have a link in your ban message. Follow it and read the entire post. That's all the info you need.

Comment: Ok, thanks, is there any number of reputation I need.  Also, why is it just now banning me from posting?

Comment: @Bart a single deleted question causing a qban  looks more like a bug to me, especially if he has been able to post more questions (which aren't downvoted)

Comment: @Manishearth One of them is zero-score, but downvoted as well as upvoted. That said, could be, but I still have to encounter the first question ban scenario that didn't have a reasonable explanation. Still, the advice in the linked post still counts.

Comment: Yep. Though I think if there's a qban he'd be on the edge, which means that a couple of upvotes ought to fix it.

Comment: Downvotes flow pretty fast for bad questions, its always suprised me that the algorithm seems to take 0 rated questions as a bad thing rather than neutral

Comment: I know, thats why I was confused.  It's all better now though.